# Passing an object-string to a javascript-function

Tags: javascript, string, object

I'm trying to pass a string like this:

```
{"key":["value"],"key2":undefined,"key3":undefined,"key4":undefined,"key5":"value"}
```

to a javascript-function like this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="myFunction(myString);">
```

but can't get the escaping right. Is there a way to pass that object-string to a function or do I need to convert something?

Greetings,
Select0r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
var myString = '{"key":["value"],"key2":undefined,"key3":undefined,"key4":undefined,"key5":"value"}';
```

**EDIT:**

In light of your recent comment I went back to the browser and tried this (works for me):

```
<a href="#" onClick="myFunction({'key':['value'],'key2':undefined,'key3':undefined,'key4':undefined,'key5':'value'});">
```

The change means that it's no longer longer passed as a string but as an object parameter to myFunction.

Comment: I tried that before and it didn't work: I get an "unterminated string literal" error.

The problem is that Javascript won't be executed in that context (special Dojo-template, IE6 ignores Javascript there) and as all Javascript needs to go inside the "onclick", there are already enclosing quotes that cause the error ...

Comment: Thanks, I guess that *would* work for me if I could only perform a str.replace on myString before passing it to myFunction. myString is passed through an AJAX-request and I can't change the result so I'm stuck with myString as it is, so my only chance is probably a different approach in generating the data in the first place ...

Answer (score 1):

As Naeem said, you can enclose the string in a single quote.  The difference between the single and double quote is this:

single quotes:

- Can contain double quotes without stopping string
- Cannot contain characters such as break lines
- Can contain single quotes via `\'`

double quotes:

- Can contain single quotes without stopping string
- Can contain break line and other special characters
- Can contain double quotes via `\"`

Comment: I guess I just have too many quotes :) The code will look something like: onclick="myFunction('{key"... while the last quotes belongs to the string and terminates the onclick-quote. As I commented above: in this special context, all Javascript needs to be inside the onclick - right now I have no idea, if that's possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, Naeem Sarfraz put me on the right track - it's not going to win a beauty contest, but it works:

As I can execute PHP in the context I'm in (but IE6 would ignore Javascript), I did a couple of replacements on single/double quotes with PHP.

```
$data = stripslashes(unserialize($data));
$data = addcslashes($data, "'");
$data = str_replace('"', "'", $data);
```

This will strip all slashes, add slashes for single quotes only and finally replace double quotes with single ones.

Now myString is in a state that can be passed to a Javascript function in onclick without quote-conflicts:

```
<a href="#" onClick="myFunction(<?php print $data; ?>);">
```

Thanks for your  contributions!

Comment: One trick that I've used in the past is to put a JSON string in an invisible element.  You can then use onclick="myFunction(eval($('#myDiv').html()))"...  I'm not sure if this makes it any easier or harder for your implementation though (also, the example does require jQuery).

Comment: I guess I stick with my replacements for now, but I'll keep that in mind, thanks. I don't work with jQuery but with Dojo so an implementation similar to yours should be no big deal.

Answer (score 0):

If you can generate code just before this `<a>` element, you can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myObj = {"key":["value"], "key2":undefined, "key3":undefined, "key4":undefined, "key5":"value"};
</script>
<a href="#" onClick="myFunction(myObj)">
```

Comment: IE6 ignores Javascript in this context completely, so I can't go with this solution.